# How to avoid left-recursion infinite loops in Fastparse?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators, left-recursion, packrat, fastparse

I had a parser that worked well in Scala Packrat parser combinators.
I would like to try something faster with the Fastparse library.
However, it cannot handle left-recursion infinite loops.
Is there any standard way to cope with that?

```
sealed trait Expr

case class Num(value: java.lang.Number) extends Expr

case class Div(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr

def num[_: P] = P(CharIn("0-9").rep(1).!).map(n => Num(n.toInt))

def div[_: P] = P(expr ~ "/" ~ expr).map(Div.tupled)

def expr[_: P]: P[Expr] = P(div | num)
```

Comment: The general answer is: rewrite your code so that recursion won't be the first choice to try out among several possibilities. I would start out with replacing `P(div | num)` with `P(num | div)` and if that won't help, rethinking the grammar on paper before attempting to change the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about Fastparse, but I'll try to answer your question nevertheless. Right now, your grammar looks something like this:

```
expr ::= div | num
div  ::= expr "/" expr
num  ::= 0 | 1 | ...
```

So if you wanted to parse `1/2` as an expression, it would first try to match `div`. To do that, it would try to match `expr` again, and basically go on infinitely. We can fix this by putting `num` before `div`, as suggested in a comment above:

```
expr ::= num | div
Or
def expr[_: P]: P[Expr] = P(num | div)
```

Success! Or is it? Upon looking more closely at the result, you'll see that it's not a `Div(Num(1), Num(2))` but rather just a `Num(1)`. To fix this, use `End`

```
def expr[_: P]: P[Expr] = P((num | div) ~ End)
```

And now it fails, saying it found "/2". It successfully matches `num` first, so it has no reason to think that that first number is part of a division operation. So we will have to use `div` before `num` after all, to make sure the bigger pattern is used, but something needs to be done to avoid recursion. We can refactor it like this:

```
expr ::= div
div  ::= num ("/" num)*
```

`div` doesn't just match division, it can also match a single number, but it tries to match division when possible. In Scala, that would be:

```
def div[_: P] = P(num ~ ("/" ~/ num).rep).map {
  case (a, ops) => ops.foldLeft(a: Expr){ case (a, b) => Div(a, b) }
}

def expr[_: P]: P[Expr] = P(div ~ End)
```

This way, we can match "1/2", "1/2/3", "1/2/3/4", etc.

Output for `parse("1/2/3/4", expr(_))` is `Parsed.Success(Div(Div(Div(Num(1),Num(2)),Num(3)),Num(4)), 7)`

Comment: I thought about a similar solution. However, I am concerned if I will have to resort to such approach all over the grammar. Isn't there a transparent solution, maybe putting some state inside `expr`?

Comment: @viyps Unfortunately, probably not. From what I can tell of Fastparse, this is the best solution. It's not that bad, though. How often do you really need left-recursion in your language?

Comment: Left recursion everywhere in the language, unfortunately.